# Mysql connection issue with remote client

Tags: mysql, connection, safe-mode

I am trying to connect to MySQL remotly but everytime I get access denied. However if i kill this process

```
root  3040 1  0 15:07 pts/0  00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid
```

I am able to connect remotely. But this thread will start everytime I restart the MySQL server. Can anyone suggest me what might be a problem?

Does the safemode thread have to run always?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's causing your problem. The documentation says: _mysqld_safe adds some safety features such as restarting the server when an error occurs and logging runtime information to an error log file._

Comment: Thanks Barmar. So whats should I be looking to check the solve the connectivity issue. Port 3306 is is open.